# Google Data Studio doesn't let me count unique boolean values using metric field

Tags: postgresql, looker-studio

I created a stacked bar chart and want to count number of true values existing in each boolean type column. So I stack them up in 3 category like A, B, C. My expected output is something like this:

```
Status   X Y Z 

A        5 2 1
B        0 3 4
C        2 4 1
```

I'm using this Postgres query:

```
 Select X, Y , Z, status, created_at
 from table abc 
 group by X, Y, Z, status, user_id, created_at
 having X or Y or Z = true
```

Issue is Data Studio is counting false values too and hence returning incorrect count on stack chart. Example: X column has only (5+2) = 7 true values present for Status column values (A and C) but it is returning more values instead. What is the correct way to show this type of data. Please help. Here is the screenshot of data studio chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

assuming x,y and z are boolean column, `having X or Y or Z = true` is the same as `having x = true or y = true or z = true` (or `having x or y or z`).

Maybe you are looking for a filtered aggregation.

```
select status, 
       created_at
       count(*) filter (where x) as num_x, 
       count(*) filter (where y) as num_y,
       count(*) filter (where z) as num_z
from the_table
group by status, created_at;
```

You also tagged version 9.4. It's not clear if that was a result of your tag spamming or if you really use this unsupported version. If you are, you need to rewrite the above as that didn't support the `filter()` clause:

```
select status, 
       created_at
       count(case when x then 1 end) as num_x, 
       count(case when y then 1 end) as num_y,
       count(case when z then 1 end) as num_z
from the_table
group by status, created_at;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
SELECT CAT,X,Y,Z
    FROM (
            SELECT  
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY CAT) ROW,
                cat,
                        SUM(IIF(ISSTATUS=1,x,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY cat) X,
                        SUM(IIF(ISSTATUS=2,x,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY cat) Y,
                        SUM(IIF(ISSTATUS=3,x,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY cat) Z

                from Table_abc
    ) t0
WHERE t0.row=1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I just have 1 query-> Why did you use this statement IIF(ISSTATUS=1,x,0)) . I think ISSTATUS is not a valid column here in my example followed by "x" value you used in all sumiff statement.

Comment: I gave my own example. Based on your example, you were not ..

But you can use it this way
IIF(ISSTATUS=x,x,0)
IIF(ISSTATUS=y,y,0)
IIF(ISSTATUS=z,z,0)